# Why was the spam flag on this post declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, declined-flags, spam

This is [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337807/ich-entwarf-diese-seite-in-schwierigkeiten-und-keine-m%C3%B6glichkeit-um-eine-gute) in question (It has been deleted after this question was posted -- users with 10K+ reputation might still be able to see it):

> Ich entwarf diese Seite in Schwierigkeiten, und keine Möglichkeit, um
>   eine gute Wirkung zu entwerfen . Erweckt den Eindruck, sieht nicht gut
>   aus, aber es ist ein guter [Laserpointer][1]
>
> [1]:
>   http://www.starklasers.com/ultra-starker-grun-laserpointer-3000mw.html
>   Bitte helfen Sie, dass, wenn man sie hier einen Link zu schicken, dann
>   suche ich es starklasers.com

As per Google Translate, the English equivalent of this would be:

> I designed this page in trouble, and no way to design a good effect.
>   Gives the impression that does not look good, but it's a good [laser
>   pointer] [1]
>
> [1]:
>   http://www.starklasers.com/ultra-starker-grun-laserpointer-3000mw.html
>   Please help, that if you send them a link, then I search it
>   starklasers.com

Maybe I am missing something here, but the post doesn't even seem to be asking a question.  There's nothing more than *go to this link* in the *question*.

I was led to think that this would be spam and flagged it such.  However, the flag was declined:

> -3 [Ich entwarf diese Seite in Schwierigkeiten, und keine Möglichkeit, um eine gute Wirkung zu entwerfen [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337807/ich-entwarf-diese-seite-in-schwierigkeiten-und-keine-m%c3%b6glichkeit-um-eine-gute) asked 2 hours ago by starklasers
>
> flagged as   spam **declined - a moderator reviewed your
>   flag, but found no evidence to support it**

Could somebody help me improve my understanding of questions and spam?

Comment: I think I agree with your flag and disagree with it being declined. I'll call it clever spam...

Comment: I raised an Other flag on that post...

Comment: Looks like the post is deleted now.

Comment: The Other flag I raised was marked helpful and the post is deleted and by the looks of it the account as well.

Comment: I've had the same issue on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305559/je-veux-acheter-un-paquet-sur-ce-site-ce-site-est-il-cr%c3%a9dible) - the title read "Je veux acheter un paquet sur ce site, ce site est-il? Crédible?" which means "I'd like to buy a package on this site, is it trustworthy?" in really poor French, probably an automated translation. I don't exactly remember the post's body but there was a spammy link to some off-topic content (pretty sure it was counterfeit clothes)...

Comment: Can we get rid of the links to the spam site please?  Don't know if Meta is trawled or not, but it seems like a bad idea regardless.

Comment: When I run into non-English spam like that I don't use the spam flag. I run it through Google Translate (as you did) then put the output in the "Other" flag option. The less work Moderators have to do the less likely a flag will be denied.

Comment: I think this german was much more worse than my english :D Anyway, since when we use an other language then english here? From a german perspective: Spam. From an Stack Overflow prespective at least: Unclear what you are asking (non english)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this looks like spam. This would probably be difficult to recognize for a moderator if they don't speak the language. Unless they follow the link.

I cast one of the close votes, but I went with the wrong reason ("not English") that another reviewer had already suggested. Which is kind of unfortunate, because I grew up speaking German. I frankly didn't read the whole thing, since the verdict seemed clear as soon as I saw that it was all German words. Sorry about missing it, I should have marked it as spam.

The post is not really proper German, by the way. "wenn man sie hier eine Link zu schicken"... that doesn't make any sense at all. It's not a sentence. I suspect that the post was generated by very poor quality auto-translation software. Or software that generates text in arbitrary languages that looks like it might be a valid post at first sight, but is complete gibberish once you read it in detail. I suspect that the text is purely an attempted decoy for the spam link, because people who don't speak the language might assume it's a valid post.

Comment: Looks like the post has been deleted now!