# Add the ability to request the Review of a declined flag

Tags: feature-request, declined-flags

There are a couple of questions in Meta like ["Why was my flag declined"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268929/why-was-the-spam-flag-on-this-post-declined), ["How do I raise a flag without getting declined by moderator?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322511/edit-war-how-do-i-raise-a-flag-without-getting-declined-by-moderator), ["Help understanding declined flags"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365445/help-understanding-declined-flags-link-to-sale-naa-request-to-help-commit-a-c) and I got a situation as well where I feel that the flag was declined in error.

Because there is no way to see [who has declined it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252858/how-can-i-find-out-who-declined-my-flag/252892?noredirect=1#252858), currently you have to take it as it is and it will be never corrected.

And I believe you can find many more examples in Meta not mentioned here.

It isn't possible to reach out to the moderator who has declined a flag because StackOverflow doesn't show who has done it. Even putting something in the chat doesn't work, nor does it help to send a detailed description in the flag request.

---

For this reason, **I'd like to raise a feature request:**

One should be able to have a declined flag reviewed (e.g. by a different moderator, so to say get a 2nd opinion). For example, if you add a button **"raise a review for this flag"** and then enter a reason for having it reviewed.

---

**Update:** Many thanks for your detailed and constructive comments and answers! This really helped to shed a light on the topic making more clear what options one has. As [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) suggested, it might be worth to put all this information gathered into a FAQ.

Comment: Being a mod is an already thankless job. There is literally no incentive to doing it _besides_ caring.

Comment: declined flags are not only caused by moderators. Declined flags can at best be turned into disputed and I'm unsure if that option exists for all declined flags, might be limited to mod flags only.

Comment: Custom flags are, which is what I think the OP is about. Matt, you may want to add that to your question. NAA flags, for example, can be community declined.

Comment: You can always raise a second mod flag, further explaining yourself. In these cases many times the original mod "recuse" themselves, leaving the flag pending for another mod to handle. More often than not the result will be exactly the same, though. Which is good, since consistent moderation is a good thing to have.

Comment: Since you've already linked to similar questions *the feature already exists*. Raise a question in Meta stating your reasons **why** you feel the flag should have been upheld. No need to re-invent the wheel here. Just brace yourself for rejection again. ☺

Comment: I won't clutter up my answer to this more general question, since I think it might be a useful FAQ. But I do want to note that your flag was declined because moderators do not consider it our job to override the closing of questions by the community. If you think a question was incorrectly closed as a duplicate, then your options are: (1) edit the question to clarify why it is not a dupe and then cast a re-open vote, (2) ping the close voter in comments and plead your case, (3) bring it to a chat room like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570), and/or (4) ask a Meta question.

Comment: To add to Cody's comment: If you do bring it to SOCVR, make sure to check our [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) as we have strict rules which posts we take into consideration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are three options already for re-visiting a flag that you think was erroneously declined:

1. **Raise the same flag again**, providing a more comprehensive explanation this time (since obviously your intended message failed to get across the first time).

   In *general*, moderators will let a different moderator handle a second re-flag. Although this isn't required, it is somewhat conventional for obvious reasons (eliminate bias, get a second set of eyes, etc.). It's also quite likely that it will happen anyway, given the lag between the flags and the cycling of the guard. (We do have to sleep once in a while, after all.)

   Do this cautiously, though. If you just raise the same flag with no new evidence or explanation, or if you use hostile wording in your new flag message, then you're very likely to annoy a moderator, which is not a good way of getting what you want. Also, I recommend only doing this *once* (for a maximum of two flags on a single issue). Moderator flags are not an appropriate venue for back-and-forth communication. See below for an option if you want a meaningful explanation and/or if some dialogue is needed.
2. **Post a question on Meta** that presents your case, references your declined flag, and asks for a re-review.

   The advantage of this is that you get a larger textbox in which to type and therefore justify yourself. You can marshal more evidence in defense of your flag, and thus you are more likely to persuade moderators that you are correct. On the other hand, if you turn out to be wrong or misunderstand the purposes of flagging, then moderators will have more room to write an explanatory answer. (Flag decline messages have strict limits in terms of the number of characters, and they are *not* meant for back-and-forth communication.)

   Furthermore—and you're on your own to determine whether this is an advantage or disadvantage—bringing the issue to Meta means it won't just be reviewed by moderators. It will be reviewed by the larger community who is interested in curation and moderatorial tasks. Since diamond moderators are elected by the community, we generally answer to that same community, so if it's clear that our initial decision or current policy is unpopular or misguided, then a discussion on Meta is a good way to go about having that changed.

   However, because it's public, this is not a good approach for sensitive matters. For that, see option #3.
3. **Contact the Stack Exchange staff** using [the "Contact Us" page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) linked in the footer of every site.

   Stack Exchange staff have moderator powers and can override elected moderator decisions. They are your ultimate escalation for when you're dissatisfied with the actions of a community-elected moderator.

We do not need to add anything else to the UI for this.

Answer (score 3):

In context to the number of flags raised per week, the number of people who raise flags only to have them declined in error is a *rounding error*.

I don't see the incentive to add yet more process to something that has plenty of process around it - posting a Meta question is more than enough to get someone the review they desire.